# I have such sentence 「いつ果てぬとも分からぬーすぐに壊れて消えてしまいそうな名前でしょう？」I can not get grammatical role of "と" and "も"

Tags: particles

I have such sentence 「いつ果てぬとも分からぬーすぐに壊れて消えてしまいそうな名前でしょう？」I can not get grammatical role of "と" and "も"

Maybe "と" is like a citing and "も" as particle which connect two verbs? Theoretically "も" has possibility to connect two verbs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of ならずとも](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21036/meaning-of-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89%e3%81%9a%e3%81%a8%e3%82%82) Also, are you sure its 果てぬ and not 果てる?